# Process on worker node isn't killed after Jenkins job is passed

Tags: jenkins, slave

I've a problem that the process on the worker node is running infinitely.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q2Sv.jpg

If I open the job for any build (353/357/358) - it was already finished. Due to this problem I face to process limit on the node and my jobs are in infinite queue.

I've tried to: 
- reboot worker node
- re-add the worker node (also using new name)
- kill the thread using Monitoring plugin (but I haven't found the respective one)

Is there any other decision except Jenkins reboot?
Current Jenkins version is 2.89.2

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after rebooting Jenkins node.